# Почему приходит пустой $_FILES?

Tags: yii2

Вот представление:

```
 <?php use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm; ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'files')->fileInput(); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton( Yii::t('app','CREATE'), [ 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Вот модель:

```
class Parser extends Model
{
    public $files;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           [['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'xml, yml']

        ];
    }
}
```

Вот контролер:

```
$execelparser = new Parser();

        if ($execelparser->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $parsers = Yii::$app->request;
            $execelparser->files = UploadedFile::getInstance($execelparser, 'files');
             return var_dump($execelparser->files);
        }else{
            return $this->render('parser',[
                'model'     => $execelparser
            ]);
        }
```

Сюда я вообще не попадаю:

```
if ($execelparser->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){}
```

потому что ничего не приходит. Если же вывести вот так:

```
return var_dump($execelparser->files);
```

получаю вот такой ответ:

```
    /var/www/magaz.lc/backend/controllers/GodsController.php:288:
object(backend\models\Parser)[89]
  public 'files' => null
  private '_errors' (yii\base\Model) => null
  private '_validators' (yii\base\Model) => null
  private '_scenario' (yii\base\Model) => string 'default' (length=7)
  private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => null
```

Если так:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request);
```

то вот такой ответ:

```
var/www/magaz.lc/backend/controllers/GodsController.php:269:
object(yii\web\Request)[8]
  public 'enableCsrfValidation' => boolean true
  public 'csrfParam' => string '_csrf-backend' (length=13)
  public 'csrfCookie' => 
    array (size=1)
      'httpOnly' => boolean true
  public 'enableCsrfCookie' => boolean true
  public 'enableCookieValidation' => boolean true
  public 'cookieValidationKey' => string 'a2vnMIxR40yJ_kbBhCdOEMBt-NkTl6TO' (length=32)
  public 'methodParam' => string '_method' (length=7)
  public 'parsers' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_cookies' => null
  private '_headers' => null
  private '_rawBody' => null
  private '_bodyParams' => null
  private '_queryParams' => null
  private '_hostInfo' => null
  private '_baseUrl' => string '/admin' (length=6)
  private '_scriptUrl' => string '/backend/web/index.php' (length=22)
  private '_scriptFile' => null
  private '_pathInfo' => string 'gods/parser' (length=11)
  private '_url' => string '/admin/gods/parser' (length=18)
  private '_port' => null
  private '_securePort' => null
  private '_contentTypes' => null
  private '_languages' => null
  private '_csrfToken' => null
  private '_isConsoleRequest' (yii\base\Request) => null
  private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => null
  private '_scriptFile' (yii\base\Request) => null
```

объясните мне, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в контроллере явно чего-то не хватает. Попробуйте привести свой код к такому виду:

```
public function upload()
{
    $execelparser = new Parser();
    if ($execelparser->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $execelparser->save()) {
        $execelparser->files = UploadedFile::getInstance($execelparser, 'files');
        if ($execelparser->files) {
            $execelparser->files->saveAs('ваш/путь/' . $execelparser->file->baseName . '.' . $execelparser->file->extension);
            $execelparser->files1 = $execelparser->file->baseName . '.' . $execelparser->file->extension; //записываем путь в бд, если нужно
    }
    return $this->render('parser',[
        'model' => $execelparser
    ]);
    }
}
```